# Should I use a logistic regression model for my predictive analytics project?

Tags: r, regression, logistic

I have been tasked with creating a machine learning model that will be used to identify what makes a customer successful such that we can look for non-existing customers that have similar characteristics to target. What makes a site “successful” will be the revenue generated from them purchasing our product.

I am planning on using R to create the model. To being with, I am planning on using geographical location, demographics of the area, claims data related to our product, number of hospitals in the area, percentage of the population who have already sought out treatment similar to ours, and a number of other data points in order to build the model.

My question is this- what sort of machine learning/predictive analytics technique would work best for my model? I have limited experience with machine learning in the past- namely, I created a logistic regression model in R a number of years ago. Would this be the best avenue to identify the characteristics of a “successful” site? My understanding from previous experience is that a logistic regression model would result in a binary outcome of 0 (non-successful site) or 1 (successful site). Would this technique make the most sense, or should I also look into a linear regression model such that successful and non-successful sites can be viewed on a relative scale? Or is there some other machine learning technique that would be even more useful in my situation?

Any help that can be provided is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: logistic regression will give you a probability output, so its already on a relative scale. However, if success is defined by revenue, then it would seem to make more sense to predict revenue and therefore use a linear regression model.

Comment: The data for your model needs to include something that allows you to see "not successful" or "less successful" examples so that you can try to see what was special about your "successful" or "more successful" examples.

Comment: Thank you for the response seanv. I will take that into consideration re predicting revenue with linear regression.

Comment: Thanks for the input Harry. I'm thinking that a number of the ideas I had above would work to show "less successful" customers. For example, percentage of the population in that metro area that has already sought out similar treatments to ours... perhaps we see that less successful sites have a larger percent of the population that is not interested in any treatments similar to the one we offer.